# ckfinder panel plugin example doesn't allow spaces

Tags: ckfinder

I've installed the ckfinder plugin example CustomPanel and it's running. One problem I have though is the formfields are not allowing me to add spaces...

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("where-no-space").on('keydown', function(e) {
                var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

                if (keyCode == 32) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var start = this.selectionStart,
                    end = this.selectionEnd,
                    value = $(this).val();

                    $(this).val(value.substring(0, start)
                            + " "
                            + value.substring(end));
                    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;

                }
            });
```

insert this function after function finder.request( 'panel:create', {}); in customPanal can fix it